# Trigger Jenkins job from Jira on demand

Tags: jenkins, automation, automated-tests, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-jira-trigger

Jenkins-Jira plugin, Is there a way to configure the plugin to trigger a build on demand?.

I am currently investigating on integrating Jenkins and Jira where a automated test case can be triggered from Jira and the results from Jenkins will be posted to Jira as a comment. (But the above trigger should be on a case basis and should not be triggered with status change to Jira ticket)

I have evaluated the scenario using Zapier (Trial version) couldn't get it as needed. Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 1):

[JIRA Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JIRA+Trigger+Plugin) is capable of triggering a job based on a comment regex pattern i.e. "Ready for testing!", etc.

[JIRA Issue Updater Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jira+Issue+Updater+Plugin) is capable of adding a comment to JIRA. You can post a link back to your Jenkins test result. When your job is successfully triggered by JIRA Trigger Plugin, you will receive an environment variable `JIRA_ISSUE_KEY` that can then be used in the `JQL for selecting issues to be updated` field. Do note that I have not tested this second part.

Answer (score 0):

Add one of the following links:

- `JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/build`
- `JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/buildWithParameters?...`

(see `JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/api` for full documentation)

to:

- [JIRA's application navigator](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/creating-links-in-the-application-navigator-802592311.html)
- an appropriate Velocity template, like in [Modifying the JIRA Footer](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira061/jira-administrators-faq/usage-faq/modifying-the-jira-footer)